# React JSX return keyword doesn't work

Tags: function, reactjs, return, jsx

It took me more than 2 hours to deeply understand the experience.

In the following snippet, `return` doesn't work as expected:

```
return
<VideoItem
    key={video.etag}
    changeVideo={changeVideo}
    video={video} />;
```

For more clarification I wanted to have `return` and what should be returned in multiple lines.

But the line below neither works:

```
return
<VideoItem key={video.etag} changeVideo={changeVideo} video={video} />;
```

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was that I had to do one of the following:

1. Write `return` and the rest in **one single line**:

   ```
   return <VideoItem key={video.etag} changeVideo={changeVideo} video={video} />;
   ```
2. Wrap the returning result with parentheses:

   ```
   return (
       <VideoItem
           key={video.etag}
           changeVideo={changeVideo}
           video={video} />);
   ```

Yes, the modern JS is THAT sensitive!

Comment: I mean... in your question you have an unclosed parenthesis. Any language that parses that correctly is... wrong...

Comment: No no, the ending uncoupled parentheses was mistakenly, I just edited it @AlexGuerra

Answer (score 0):

All your content should be wrapped inside a parent tag.
A typical return syntax looks like so:

```
return (
  <div>
    Everything you do should be here.......
  </div>
);
```

Notice the parent `<div></div>`. You can change it to anything like `<h1></h1>`, `<b></b>`, etc.

Comment: That was not about the parent element, but the wrapping `parentheses`.